# Laravel return model between two dates

Tags: php, database, laravel-5, eloquent

I am trying to eager load a model and return records between two dates, but if nothing is found between the two dates I want to return the next closest record, I have tried the following:

```
$query->with(['hives' => function($q) use ($start_date, $end_date) {
                                $q->whereIn('hive_type_id',[3,4]);
                                $q->whereBetween('logged_at',[$start_date, $end_date]);
                                $q->where('active',true)->where('logged_at','<=',$end_date);
                           }]);
```

Have tried chaining `$q->orWhere('active',true)->where('logged_at','<=',$end_date)` but this doesn't seem to make a difference.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this might help you

```
$query->with(['hives' => function($q) use ($start_date, $end_date) {
    $q->whereIn('hive_type_id',[3,4]); // you can wrap this in below if belong to first condition 
    $q->where(function ($qr) use ($start_date, $end_date){
      $qr->whereBetween('logged_at',[$start_date, $end_date]);
    });
    $q->orWhere(function ($qr) use ($end_date){
      $qr->where('active',true)->where('logged_at','<=',$end_date);
    });
}]);
```